# Putting a bar on the bottom of the UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using the UIPageViewController in my storyboard and I want to create a bar on the bottom of the screen with a label on it. So something like the navigation bar, this always stays there when you switch pages from the UIPageViewController. However on my storyboard I cannot drop a view or label on the PageViewController, how can I achieve this?
Example:
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be on top of/overlapping the UIPageViewController, or just be positioned below it?

Comment: Positioned below, like the navigation bar. It always needs to stay there when you scroll pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embed the PageViewController in a container which is added on another View controller. This image will explain it better.

[image]

Once that is done you can add the custom view as a subview over it.